# Submit ChoiceField form Django

Tags: python, django, forms, post, choicefield

I'm dealing with how make a custom form in Django and now I'm stuck on the submit step.

When I press submit, I'm getting an `__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'networkList'`.

My `forms.py` it's:

```
class SimpleDeploy(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, networkList, policiesList, applicationList, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleDeploy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if networkList and policiesList and applicationList:
            self.fields['Network Partition ID:'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=networkList)
            self.fields['Application Policy ID:'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=policiesList)
            self.fields['Application ID:'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=applicationList)
        else:
            self.fields['Network Partition ID:'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices='No network partitions found')
            self.fields['Application Policy ID'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices='No application policies found')
            self.fields['Application ID:'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices='No applications found')
```

On my `views.py` the method looks like:

```
def simpleDeploy(request):
    netList = getDetailsNetworkPartitions(request)
    polList = getDetailsApplicationPolicies(request)
    appList = getDetailsApplications(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SimpleDeploy(request.POST, networkList=None, policiesList=None, applicationList=None)
        if form.is_valid():
            network = form.cleaned_data['Network Partition ID:']
            policy = form.cleaned_data['Application Policy ID:']
            application = form.cleaned_data['Application ID:']
            ##### more things
        else:
            simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(networkList=netList, policiesList=polList, applicationList=appList)
    else:
        simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(networkList=netList, policiesList=polList, applicationList=appList)
    return render(request, 'apacheStratos/simpleDeploy.html', {'form': simpleForm})
```

The traceback error:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/iago/Escritorio/tfm/website/apacheStratos/views.py" in simpleDeploy
  60.         form = SimpleDeploy(request.POST, networkList=None, policiesList=None, applicationList=None)

Exception Type: TypeError at /stratos/simpleDeploy
Exception Value: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'networkList'
```

Looking at the doc, I read that the POST request it's always the first parameter (`request.Post`) and on the init method I think it corresponds with the `self`, moreover on other answers here I saw that sometimes, putting `data=params` works but in my case I get an error: `need more than 1 value to unpack` on the line `if form.is_valid():`

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/iago/Escritorio/tfm/website/apacheStratos/views.py" in simpleDeploy
  61.         if form.is_valid():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  184.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  176.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  392.         self._clean_fields()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  407.                     value = field.clean(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/forms/fields.py" in clean
  163.         self.validate(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/forms/fields.py" in validate
  868.         if value and not self.valid_value(value):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.12-py2.7.egg/django/forms/fields.py" in valid_value
  878.         for k, v in self.choices:

Exception Type: ValueError at /stratos/simpleDeploy
Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

So, where it's my mistake? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined your form init so that the first positional argument is `networkList`; so when you do `form = SimpleDeploy(request.POST, networkList=None...)`, both the positional arg and the keyword arg both go to the same name, which isn't allowed.

Don't change the signature at all; get the extra values from kwargs.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    networkList = kwargs.pop('networkList', None)
    policiesList = kwargs.pop('policiesList', None)
    applicationList = kwargs.pop('applicationList', None)
    super(...)
```

Alternatively, since you only need those values inside the form, you might consider just passing the request to this method and getting those values directly there; the same syntax would apply.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. I've changed the signature as you suggested and now works. But I'm still getting "need more than 1 value to unpack on the line if form.is_valid():" error. On the post data I can see that the values are correct: 
(Variable                                       Value)
Network Partition ID:  u'network-partition-2'
Application ID:     u'eb2ed6ea-922f-2e56-0129-c0e1c1899ec5'
Application Policy ID:  u'application-policy-2'

csrfmiddlewaretoken u'BxsGuIE0iI80wJBkTEXF0sIEmLWXfn2t'

Or I need pass also a tuple? Thanks.

Comment: You should show what the `getDetailsNetworkPartitions` and similar functions return. Choices need to be a series of 2-tuples; are you just returning a simple list?

Comment: On the submit, yes. Because I want the values that the user has selected but when I fill the form the getDetailsNetworkPartitions(request), getDetailsApplicationPolicies(request), getDetailsApplications(request) they return a tuple like (u'network-partition-2', u'network-partition-2'). On the submit, reading on other anwsers you get the first element of the tuple (the id of the choice selected) or I've understood wrong? It needs to be a tuple also?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. Choices are choices, it makes no different whether you are in the submit are not.

Comment: Mmmm, to fill the form, the 3 funcions return a tuple ('id','display_name'). I don't get an error rendering the template, the error happens when I press submit.

Comment: But you're passing them in as None on submit. Why? How can you expect this to work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on Django. I thought that as I have filled the choicefields before when rendering the template I didn't need pass the data again on the submit, because when you press submit, the form has been filled before. Now it works. Thanks for your help and patience!